# How to convert MySQLi connector to PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

I am reading this book "PHP and MySQL Web Development by Luke Welling Laura Thomson Fourth Edition" page 751 for those of you who are familiar with this book.
However, the solution provided in the book is using MySQLi DB Connector which works fine when tested.  I would like to adopt this solution to one of my project which uses PHP PDO Connector, but I am having a problem by trying to derive to the same results as the text book do. I am seeking a little help in converting the MySQLi Connector to handle the PDO process. Both examples are using MySQL DB.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong and seeking little help.

I am trying to get my PDO procedure to produce the same result for the extended array  upon the children id's as the original text book array do for it to work.

```
// Example taken from the text book
function expand_all(&$expanded) {
    // mark all threads with children as to be shown expanded
    $conn = db_connect();
    $query = "select postid from header where children = 1";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    $num = $result->num_rows;
    for($i = 0; $i<$num; $i++) {
        $this_row = $result->fetch_row();
        $expanded[$this_row[0]]=true;
    }
}

// The print_r form the text book example looks like this:
// result:
mysqli_result Object (  [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 1 
                        [lengths] => [num_rows] => 3 [type] => 0 
                      ) 

// expended:
   Array ( [0] => 1 ) Array ( [0] => 2 ) Array ( [0] => 4 ) 

//--------------------------------------------------------------//

// Know, here is my new adopted changes for using PHP PDO connector  
function expand_all(&$expanded)
{
    // mark all threads with children to be shown as expanded
    $table_name = 'header';
    $num = 1; 

    $sql = "SELECT postid FROM $table_name WHERE children = :num";

    try
    {
        $_stmt = $this->_dbConn->prepare($sql);
        $_stmt->bindParam(":num", $num, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $_stmt->execute();

        $result  = $_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);          

        // get the $expanded children id's
        foreach ($result as $key => $value) 
        { 
            foreach ($value as $k => $val)
            {
                $expanded[$k] = $val;
            }
        }
        return $extended;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        die($this->_errorMessage = $e);
    }

    //close the database  
    $this->_dbConn = null;          
}

// The print_r for the result looks like this:
 Array ( [0] => Array ( [children_id] => 1 ) 
         [1] => Array ( [children_id] => 2 ) 
         [2] => Array ( [children_id] => 4 ) 
        ) 

// The return extended print_r for the children id's
// look like this:
    Array ( [children_id] => 4);
```

Comment: So what's the difference you see?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` and since each result has the same column names you are overriding the values on each iteration of your loop.

If you want $exapnded to be an array of ids you need to adjust your loop or you should use `PDO::FETCH_COLUMN`.

With loop adjustment:

```
   foreach ($result as $key => $value) 
    { 
        foreach ($value as $k => $val)
        {
            $expanded[] = $val;
        }
    }
    return $expanded;
```

With fetch mode adjustment:

```
    $_stmt = $this->_dbConn->prepare($sql);
    $_stmt->bindParam(":num", $num, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $_stmt->execute();

    $result  = $_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);

    // at this point im not sure whay you are both passing 
    // $expanded by reference and returning it...
    // if you want to overwrite this array just do $expanded = $result
    // if you need to add these items TO an existing $expanded you can use
    // $expanded = array_merge($expanded, $result)
```

Both of these methods shoudl give you an array like:

```
Array(
  0 => 1,
  1 => 2,
  2 => 4
)
```

Comment: I see your point here and in agreement, but this answer will produce a single array in which the text book example produces 4 arrays for the expanded children id's.  So, how could I go about doing the same, or is it because they are using a for loop?